# Finding the p-value of the pearson correlation between two non square matrices in R without rcorr() library

Tags: python, r

I have two non square matrices that i need to find the pearson correlation values and the associated p-values between each other. I'm aware of the **rcorr()** library, but the RAM memory usage with this library is huge - i have two enormous matrices and i'm unable to use **rcorr()**.

Using the **cor()** library, i was able to obtain the correlation values. With this correlation array, is possible to make a function to obtain the p-values, without **rcorr()**??

**ps.** I also tried to look into Python to do this, but i was only able to found libraries that do not accept non-square matrices such as **pearsonr** and **linegress** from **scipy.stat**.

```
 data1 <- matrix(runif(30),ncol=5)
 data2 <- matrix(runif(24),ncol=4)
 correlation <-cor(data1,data2,method='pearson')
 correlation
            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]         [,4]
[1,] -0.63451452  0.8311530 -0.18859842  0.004892728
[2,]  0.66676636 -0.8633116  0.02666929  0.010362925
[3,] -0.03299319 -0.4435478  0.06281622 -0.502668829
[4,] -0.79032734  0.7334099 -0.13531482  0.087650016
[5,] -0.02617180  0.5419900  0.67293404  0.112950907
```

Comment: Is `ltm::rcor.test()` any use? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14068714/3022126

Comment: rcor.test() uses the values of just one matrix (in this case, i need the correlation between two matrices)

Answer (score 1):

Most tests assume for the null hypothesis that the inputs come from independent normally distributed data

They then test `t = r * sqrt(n-2) / sqrt(1-r^2)` as a *t*-statistic with `n-2` degrees of freedom

So you could try something like this (no extra packages beyond base `stats`)

```
p <- function(t, d) { 1 - 2 * abs(pt(t, d) - 1/2) }
t <- function(r, n) { r * sqrt(n-2) / sqrt(1-r^2) }
rownum <- 6
set.seed(1)
data1 <- matrix(rnorm(5*rownum), nrow=rownum)
data2 <- matrix(rnorm(4*rownum), nrow=rownum)
correlation <- cor(data1, data2, method='pearson')
correlation
p(d(correlation, rownum), rownum-2)
```

giving correlations of

```
            [,1]        [,2]       [,3]        [,4]
[1,] -0.52736212 -0.22015909  0.4017038 -0.09294361
[2,]  0.02056352  0.04304460  0.3434117  0.24733758
[3,]  0.40489453  0.73092841 -0.2950121 -0.83761011
[4,]  0.28672335 -0.07727180 -0.3430130 -0.02175433
[5,]  0.52745346  0.09179105 -0.7022999 -0.10932760
```

and *p*-values of

```
    [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
[1,] 0.2822894 0.67509693 0.4298549 0.86098603
[2,] 0.9691591 0.93547298 0.5051319 0.63655918
[3,] 0.4258473 0.09885895 0.5703196 0.03741457
[4,] 0.5817008 0.88432299 0.5056595 0.96737366
[5,] 0.2821905 0.86270012 0.1197462 0.83666197
```

one of which is less than 0.05, hardly a surprise since you have 20 values.

Compare the numbers in the bottom right of these matrices with the results of

```
> cor.test(data1[,5], data2[,4])

        Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  data1[, 5] and data2[, 4]
t = -0.21997, df = 4, p-value = 0.8367
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.8458408  0.7706066
sample estimates:
       cor 
-0.1093276
```

so this method seems to produce the same answer for the correlation and *p*-value